# Bold cells in kable (format = latex) based on rowwise largest value by group of variables

Tags: r, latex, conditional-formatting, kable

Working Example

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(  x1 = rnorm(3), x2 = rnorm(3), z1 =rnorm(3), z2=rnorm(3))
```

which produces

```
 x1       x2       z1       z2
-------  -------  -------  -------
 -1.207   -2.346   -0.575   -0.890
  0.277    0.429   -0.547   -0.477
  1.084    0.506   -0.564   -0.998
```

I can then export to latex using

```
kable(df,format = "latex", digits = 3)
```

But I would like to have in bold the cells that are the largest across rows (x1 vs x2, and z1 vs z2). So in this example, x1=-1.207 and z1=-0.575 would be in bold in the first row, x2=0.429 and z2=-0.477 would be in bold in the second row, etc.

So that the final output should be

```
\begin{tabular}{r|r|r|r}
\hline
x1 & x2 & z1 & z2\\
\hline
\textbf{-1.207} & -2.346 & \textbf{-0.575} & -0.890\\
\hline
0.277 & \textbf{0.429} & -0.547 & \textbf{-0.477}\\
\hline
\textbf{1.084} & 0.506 & \textbf{-0.564} & -0.998\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using cell conditional formatting from `kableExtra` coupled with `tidyverse` packages this is one attempt, although I'd be the first to admit it seems alot of work.

I'm sure there is a better way.

````
```{r results='asis'}

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
library(stringr)
library(kableExtra)

set.seed(1234)

df <-
  data.frame( x1 = rnorm(3), x2 = rnorm(3), z1 = rnorm(3), z2 = rnorm(3)) %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  pivot_longer(-rowid)%>%
  mutate(group = str_sub(name, 1, 1),
  id = str_sub(name, -1, -1)) %>%
  group_by(group, rowid) %>%
  mutate(value = round(value, 3),
  value = ifelse(value == max(value), cell_spec(sprintf("%.3f", value), "latex", bold = TRUE),
                 sprintf("%.3f", value))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-c(group, id)) %>%
  pivot_wider() %>% 
  select(-rowid)


kbl(df,
    booktabs = TRUE,
    escape = FALSE,
    align = "r")
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! yes it's long but at least I understand how to do it, and can try to make a function out of it. It's super useful for me (table with a lot of numbers from Monte Carlo simulation) and want to highlight which statistical approach performs best (bolded value).